# Protractor-fail-fast npm fails spec and doesn't run the rest specs (tests) in config file (using Protractor with Jasmine)

Tags: npm, jasmine, protractor, jasmine2.0, fail-fast

I have an issue while using npm protractor-fail-fast. ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-fail-fast )
If one spec file is failed, the rest specs will be NOT executed (NOT GOOD).

I'm searching an approach how to fail describe with many 'it' blocks, when first expectation is failed and the rest 'it' blocks will NOT be executed.
In the meantime, the rest spec file in config file SHOULD BE executed.

Could you please give your recommendations? Is it possible to implement this solution using Protractor + Jasmine ?